# Playing YUV on VLC Player

Tags: vlc

When playing a raw video (.yuv) file on VLC Player. How can I tell VLC the width, height and frame-rate of the video?

Answer (score 38):

Try this:

```
vlc --demux rawvideo --rawvid-fps 25 --rawvid-width 1920 --rawvid-height 1080 --rawvid-chroma I420 input.yuv
```

Comment: `--demux rawvideo` broke this for me.. the other options work fine for playing yuv though.

Comment: I don't see why you need --demux, so I removed that from my command line. Works well for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`--demux rawvideo` was neither helpful or harmful, for my purposes, but the correct chroma choice happened to be `--rawvid-chroma UYVY`.  If uncertain, just *experiment*: you won't get crashes, just wonky imagery.