# What is the YUV format? (from the point of view of a beginner who do not know how to play it)

Tags: yuv

A video quality metric called [VMAF](https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf) by Netflix evaluate videos in YUV format.

But what is the YUV format? Why can not I play the YUV format video by VLC which claims to be able to play almost any kind of video format, for example, an MP4 file encoded in x264?

I read the Wikipedia, but I still do not get it.

Comment: You may look at my post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040944/convert-yuv444-to-yuv422-images/39048445#39048445](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040944/convert-yuv444-to-yuv422-images/39048445#39048445). It's not going to answer your question, but it might give you some incite. Might confuse as well...

Answer (score 28):

My explanation may not be accurate, but I am comfortable in reading [YUV on Wikipidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV)  only after I know the following.

First, let's consider how a monitor displays an image. Every color can be represented by three colors (the so-called RGB model), that is, red, green and blue. Every "red", "green" and "blue" can be recorded in a computer in 1 byte (8 bit). So a pixel in a monitor has 3 bytes (each byte for "red", "green" and "blue") information.

Human beings' eye is very sensible on brightness, but not so much on color. Can we make use of that? So it comes the YUV representation of color. "Y" means luminance (brightness), "U" and "V" means chrominance (color). YUV is like RGB which is used to represent a color. But why do we need it while we can represent color in RGB model?

Becuase the file size matters. In RGB model we have to use 3 bytes (24 bits) to record a color, but in YUV model, we can half the size if we use yuv420p format. You do not have to know what yuv420p is, the point here is that use YUV we can dramatically decrease the file size (very easily) than using RGB model.

When you play an MP4 file encoded in x264, you can see the file is decoded in yuv420 planar (check that in your VLC player by opening "codec information"). VLC needs metadata to be able to display the video properly, which is why things like MP4 exist. YUV is raw data, which does not contain the height and width information needed.
Check here for how to play it :[Playing YUV on VLC Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882375/playing-yuv-on-vlc-player)
Check here for an explaination about why you need the metadata: [How to find out resolution and count of frames in YUV 4:2:0 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677747/how-to-find-out-resolution-and-count-of-frames-in-yuv-420-file)

Comment: YUV color space is not all about data compression. Many image processing  and computer vision algorithms apply different processing for the Y channel than U and V channels (algorithms which can't work with RGB color space). Very nice answer though...

Comment: If you save as YUV4mpeg format, input parameters are saved in the file and do not need to be supplied on the command line.

Comment: Fun fact: the reason corrupted videos often look solid green is that the Y channel is luminance, whereas the U and V are the green-blue and green-red axes. (This was originally for backwards compatibility with black-and-white TVs, where the U and V channels could just be ignored.) But if U and V are present but equal to 0, then “white” luminance is displayed as green.