# iOS default camera raw frames format

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-camera

I am new to iOS development and I need to capture camera frames and convert them into yuv420 to perform h264 encoding. In my android application, I used the libyuv to do the conversions. Now I want to replicate the same thing with in iOS. I was wondering what options do I have and how do I receive camera callback with datas in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to use ffmpeg in your project, see this question (it's not about iOS programming, but it's possible to compile ffmpeg and link it in an iOS app).
[convert H264 video to raw YUV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609760/convert-h264-video-to-raw-yuv-format)

P.S. Also try to compile libyuv for iOS architecture, maybe it's easier yo use it instead of ffmpeg :)

https://code.google.com/p/libyuv/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 1):

When capturing raw image data from the camera, you can specify the pixel format of the output buffer in the `videoSettings` property of the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` of your capture session.

Pixel formats such as `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar` or `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8PlanarFullRange` will probably give you a good starting point for additional processing to get to the exact format that you need.

I also recommend that you look into Apple's "[AV Foundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW3)", especially into the chapter about [Still and Video Media Capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2%20in).